# Создать GET запрос в базу данных (mysql)

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, get

Есть база данных с двумя пользователями (USER 1 , USER 2) и переменные для USER 1 переменная VAR (x1 , x2) и тоже самое  для USER 2 переменная VAR (x1 , x2) ,но значения разные для этих USER .

Ранее я уже пробовал написать запрос ,но все таки отображало не то .Думал реализовать такую штуку чтоб в запросе GET если (например) для USER-1 , VAR-x2 ,VAL =11 то в адресной строчке показывает это значение ,а если же например не сходиться с данными таблицы то тогда пишет VAL= error в адресной строке.
И отправлять не через форму ,а через адресную строку типа http://localhost/plc_server/plc_var.php?USER=1&VAR=x2&VAL=11 это будет правильно,а если вместо VAL=11 будет например число 300 а не 11 то выдаст ошибку. Можно пример (только простой без использования PDO, лучше MYSQLI) ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Научись формулировать свой вопрос. Зачем что-то показывать в адресной строке? При чем тут phpMyAdmin?

Comment: Я имел ввиду ,если я прописал например http://localhost/plc_server/plc_var.php?user=1&var=x2&val=11 и val сошлось с тем что в таблице то тогда показывает как есть ,а если же я вписываю не достоверные данные ,например val 300 то тогда выдает ошибку

Comment: Ну так сделай запрос `SELECT COUNT() FROM WHERE f1= AND f2= AND f3=` и посмотри что он вернет. Вернет `1` - значит такая запись есть, `0` - значит нет.

Comment: Как это будет смотреться на моем примере с базой данных? Можешь продемонстрировать пожалуйста ?

Comment: @dron ты можешь объяснить, зачем тебе нужна эта галиматья с адресной строкой и почему ты не можешь выполнить примитивный запрос SELECT?

Comment: @Ипатьев потому-что мне форма для ввода не нужна .А через SELECT будет сильно громоздко , так как пока что только 2 пользователя,а потом будет десяток и на каждого писать запрос не совсем правильно наверное.

Comment: ну то есть ты вообще что ли не умеешь работать с БД из ПХП?

Comment: @Ипатьев в целом можно конечно `SELECT id LIMIT 1` будет побыстрее.

Comment: Умею но на базовом уровне ,по этому прошу наглядный пример с использованием моей таблицы(

Comment: Извини, но выполнение запроса SELECT - это и есть базовый уровень. Базовее него нет ничего

Comment: Где ты там увидел "запрос на каждого"? Ты вообще знаком с таким понятием, как "переменная"? Хотя бы из курса математики за третий класс?

Comment: Вот здесь WHERE user=? and var=? and val=?" .   вместо знаков вопросов ставим например user=1 and var=х1 and val=10  , но это только для одного идет сравнение .А если надо для  user=2 and var=х1 and val=21 ?

Comment: Тогда будет другой урл - `plc_var.php?user=2&var=x1&val=21`. Ты вообще понимаешь как веб-то работает?

Comment: НЕ СТАВИМ НИЧЕГО ВМЕСТО ЗНАКОВ ВОПРОСОВ! В этом вся суть!!! Вместо знака вопроса подставится переменная из урла! Если в урл будет plc_var.php?user=2, то вместо знака вопроса САМО ПОДСТАВИТСЯ 2

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ну в общем, чтобы выполнить запрос к mysql с использованием переменной, надо сделать следующее

```
// создаем запрос SQL в котором все переменные заменены на знак вопроса
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user=? and var=? and val=?";
// подготоваливаем запрос
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql); 
// привязываем переменные к запросу
// указывая тип для каждой переменной. для простоты всегда можно использовать тип "s"
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $_GET['user'], $_GET['var'], $_GET['val']);
// выполняем запроc
$stmt->execute();
// получаем результат
$result = $stmt->get_result();
// из результата получаем строку
$user = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

и дальше уже можем проверить, вернула БД данные или нет

```
if ($user) {
    echo "OK";
} else {
    echo "error";
}
```

Переменная $conn содержит подключение mysqli. Сначала учимся, [как правильно подключаться к mysqli](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/mysqli_connect)

Comment: Этот пример хорош если не много пользователей ,а если их 30 человек ? То на каждого запрос писать ?

Comment: Какие 30 человек, откуда? В урле только один ИД юзера.